# Pyspark: writing data to Postgres using JDBC

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, pyspark

1) I am reading table from Postgres as below and creating a dataframe

```
df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", url). \
                        option("query", "SELECT * FROM test_spark"). \
                            load()
```

2) Updating the one value in the dataframe df

```
newDf = df.withColumn('id',F.when(df['id']==10,20).otherwise(df['id']))
```

3) I am trying to upsert the data back Postgres table.

--Below code is clearing out the table data

```
newDf.write.mode("overwrite").option("upsert", True).\
        option("condition_columns", "id").option("truncate", True).\
        format("jdbc").option("url", url).option("dbtable", "test_spark").save()
```

--Below code is working fine.

```
newDf.write.mode("overwrite").option("upsert", True).\
        option("condition_columns", "id").option("truncate", True).\
        format("jdbc").option("url", url).option("dbtable", "test_spark1").save()
```

**Issue: When I am trying to write the updated dataframe back to same table (i.e test_spark) the table data is getting cleared out, but when it is new table (i.e non existing table) it's working fine.**

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're encountering is due to how Apache Spark's DataFrameWriter handles the 'overwrite' save mode. When 'overwrite' mode is specified, it first *truncates* or *drops* the table before writing the new data.

However, the problem here is that Spark uses lazy evaluation, where computation on RDD/DataFrame/Dataset is not immediately executed when an action is invoked. The actual computation is triggered only when an action like `count()`, `first()`, `take()`, `collect()`, `show()`, etc., is called. Because of this, when you call some functions/methods aiming at saving data in 'overwrite' mode, such as, for example, `df.write.jdbc` with mode 'overwrite' or similar code like the one in your question, Spark doesn't have the data in `df` computed yet. It first drops the table and then computes `df`, but at this point, the `df` is empty because the table has already been dropped.

In essence, the flow of your program is currently:

1. Define the `df` computation (read from the table).
2. Drop the table (as part of 'overwrite').
3. Actually compute `df` and write it to the table (but `df` is empty because the table was dropped before `df` was computed).

To resolve this, you need to force the computation of `df` before you overwrite the table. You can use an action like `df.cache()` after you create `df` to force its computation. Here is an example:

```py
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=database_url, table='test_spark', properties=database_properties)


df.cache()  # forces computation of df
df.show()

df.write.jdbc(url=database_url, table='test_spark', mode='overwrite', properties=database_properties)

df = spark.read.jdbc(url=database_url, table='test_spark', properties=database_properties)
df.show()
```

In the updated code, `df.cache()` triggers the computation of `df` and caches the result. Now, when `df.write.jdbc` is called, `df` has already been computed, and the data is not lost when the table is dropped or truncated by the `write`.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue by writing the dataframe to checkpoint directory before writing it to DB table as shown in the code below

```
     sparkContext.setCheckpointDir('checkpoints')
     newDf.checkpoint().write.format("jdbc").option("url", url).option("truncate", "true").mode("overwrite").\
                option("dbtable", "spark_test").save()
```